# jersey rest web services multiple format

Tags: rest, jersey

how to return the correct representation based on URI

example

/text.json should return json

/text.xml should return xml

/text should return plain text

All these are mapped to the same method

@GET
public Contact getContacts()
{

}

Comment: If you are creating webservice as opposed to user facing service you might want considering content type negotiation (@Produces annotation in JAX-RS). This would leave you with single uri /text and content type will be declared in request headers (this is more RESTful aproach).

Answer (score 3):

The answer can be found in this post: http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/extension-custom-negotiation-td3078866.html

Essentially you configure a ResourceConfig https://jersey.dev.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.1.0-ea/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html

You need to extend an implementation of ResourceConfig [1] and override the media type mappings method.

For example you can do the following:

```
package foo;

public class MyResourceConfig extends PackagesResourceConfig {
    public PackagesResourceConfig(Map<String, Object> props) {
        super(props);
    }

    public Map<String, MediaType> getMediaTypeMappings() {
        Map<String, MediaType> m = new HashMap<String, MediaType> ();
        m.put("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        m.put("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);
        return m;
    }
}
```

and you can register your "MyResourceConfig" as described here:

https://jersey.dev.java.net/documentation/1.1.0-ea/user-guide.html#d4e115

In the above example your web.xml would need to container:

```
<web-app>
     <servlet>
         <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
             <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
             <param-value>foo.MyResourceConfig</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <init-param>
             <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>org.foo.rest;org.bar.rest</param-value>
         </init-param>
     </servlet>
     ....
```